# Image display from database

Tags: php

I am trying to display an image from database with blob datatype,
I tried all code from all sites and videos but I can't get a result.

```
$db =  new mysqli ("localhost","root","","catchyourbook"); 
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `diplo computer engg`");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['Front page'] ).'"/>';   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><img src='$row[Front page].png' height="150px" width="300px"></td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: Why are you saving the image in the database in the first place? And from what I see you have 2 images in there, which one is not working and what error/warning message do you have ?

Comment: I would rename your columns to be normalized. What does `Front page` actual contain?

Comment: Front page is a column name of database where a image is stored in database.